# How to match nth occurance in a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl

```
set string {rose is an flower jasmine is a flower rose is an flower rose is a colour jasmine is a flower}
```

From the above string I want to match `rose is an flower` and `rose is a colour`.

So I did regexp like below,

```
% puts [regexp -all {rose.+?(flower|colour)} $string]
3
```

from the above o/p we had three matches.

```
% puts [regexp -all -inline {rose.+?(flower|colour)} $string]
{rose is an flower} flower {rose is an flower} flower {rose is a colour} colour
```

From the above output am expecting:

```
{rose is an flower} {rose is an flower} {rose is a colur}
```

I don't know how the below highlighted words are coming

```
{rose is an flower} flower {rose is an flower} flower {rose is a colour} colour
                    ^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^
```

If someone explains, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 4):

Subexpressions surrounded by parentheses `()` define capture groups that will be extracted for you separately. From the [manuals](http://wiki.tcl.tk/396):

> (regular expression)`
>       Parenthesis surrounding one ore more regular expressions specify a nested regular expression or choice of several regular expressions.
>   The substring matching the nested regular expression is captured and
>   can be referred to via the back reference mechanism, and alo captured
>   into the corresponding match variable specified as an arbument to the
>   command.

If you do not want to extract a capture group, you just add `?:` at the beginning of the parentheses, in which case they'll just define a sub expression:

```
%puts [regexp -all -inline {rose.+?(?:flower|colour)} $string]
{rose is an flower} {rose is an flower} {rose is a colour}
```

Comment: In addition, non-capturing groups can be compiled by the RE engine much more efficiently. In some cases, Tcl detects automatically that it can use this more efficient mode of working, but that's not the case with `regexp -inline`, as that reports all capture groups…

Comment: Whereas if you need the capture groups (e.g., because of backreferences in the RE) then you just have to postprocess the returned list (e.g., with a multi-variable `foreach` or `lmap`).

Answer (score 1):

**Watch out with Lazy Quantifiers in Tcl**

Tcl lazy quantifiers are unreliable when followed by an alternation because they want to return the longest match (so they may jump further than you expect). Use this regex instead:

```
rose(?:(?!flower|colour).)*(?:flower|colour)
```

See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/1).

Comment: Doesn't apply in this case; there are positive, non-empty string matches on either side of the non-greedy part that anchor things strongly. With a greedy match, the questioner's RE would match once (of virtually the whole string)…

Comment: @DonalFellows What I was trying to say was that `rose.*?(?!flower|colour)` (the normal solution in another engine) might not be reliable here. Though `flower` and `colour` are the same length, so it might just work. But what if he uses different words? Just a general observation about Tcl, `.*?` followed by an alternation looks for the longest match.

Comment: @zx81 Where did that negative lookahead come from?

Comment: @Jerry it's a DIY pseudo-`.*?` I made on the spur of the moment for an engine with a `.*?` "challenge": AFAIK, in Tcl `.*?` followed by an alternation will look for the longest match, hence the need for something more reliable. See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/1)

Comment: Err I don't get it? `rose.*?(?!flower|colour)` is something completely different and doesn't match like `rose(?:(?!flower|colour).)*(?:flower|colour)` at all.

Comment: @Jerry On your demo the `.*?` works perfectly. Not a Tcl expert, just repeating what I read—it might be obsolete. `Tcl 8.6 is inconsistent in the way it handles lazy quantifiers in regular expressions with alternation because it attempts to match the longest alternative, instead of being eager and accepting the first alternative that matches` <= RB4. Going to bed, catch you mañana. :)

Comment: Err, I don't think what you read was correct. I can't replicate this on my machine where I have 8.6 installed.

Comment: @Jerry I might ask Jan where he got that info, only I'll make it low priority as I don't want to burden him too much. :)