# How to match the my expected output through regular expression using TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

The below one is my real scenario:

I will have output as below:

> Neighbour Group : Testing
>
> Server Address - 10.0.0.1  Neighbour Group         : Testing      Date
>   :Jul 08 18:26:32 2014  Queries Pending         :     0/1
>   Requesting Method :Round-robin   Server Address - 20.0.0.1  Neighbour
>   Group         : Testing      Date             :Jul 08 18:26:32 2014 
>   Queries Pending         :     0/1     Requesting Method :Round-robin
>
> Server Address - 30.0.0.1  Neighbour Group         : Testing      Date
>   :Jul 08 18:26:32 2014  Queries Pending         :     0/1
>   Requesting Method :Round-robin

From the all above output I want to group the output in a TCL list,

I want to capture from (starting delimiter) where `Server Address` starts in the given string  to the `word before` where next time `Server Address` coming.

So, for first server, regexp output should be like:

> {Server Address - 10.0.0.1  Neighbour Group         : Testing
>   Date             :Jul 08 18:26:32 2014  Queries Pending         :
>   0/1     Requesting Method :Round-robin}

So, for second server, regexp output should be like:

> {Server Address - 20.0.0.1  Neighbour Group         : Testing
>   Date             :Jul 08 18:26:32 2014  Queries Pending         :
>   0/1     Requesting Method :Round-robin}

And same, for third server, starting delimiter is `Server Address` then afterwards there is no another ending delimiter such as `Server Address`. So, in that case it should go and find up to last character of the given string.

for third server after regexp output should be like

> {Server Address - 30.0.0.1  Neighbour Group         : Testing
>   Date             :Jul 08 18:26:32 2014  Queries Pending         :
>   0/1     Requesting Method :Round-robin }

Comment: Please use the code markup, not quote markup, when pasting code.

Comment: How does this relate to **[this other question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630459/how-to-match-nth-occurance-in-a-string-using-regular-expression)** on which you got several responses already? You can't use the answers from that question?

Comment: @zx81 Beat me to it :)

Comment: Have you tried the, to me obvious, `{rose is an flower}` pattern? This gave me your expected result - am I missing something?

Comment: @Jerry You owe me a lemon juice (no sugar please).

Comment: @zx81 And you still need to ask your source about that other claim of Tcl lazy quantifiers for me :)

Comment: @Jerry I will, I will. I'm a bit reluctant to disturb him but I will. I'm guessing it has to do with the DFA/NFA mixed bag of tricks.

Comment: Sorry all, i changed the question now

Comment: @velpandian What have you tried? Your previous regex was a step more complex than one that would give you the above output...

Comment: @Jerry and all  Am sorry again, i thought of asking something else by mistake i didn't read carefully before post. now again changed the question

Comment: Did you try Donal's current regexp? It should be working to your real situation.

Comment: yes it is working perfectly for my real situation

Answer (score 2):

For the updated question, the pattern `rose.*?flower` seems to do the trick.

```
% set string {rose is an flower rose is an flower rose is a flower rose is a color and an flower}
% set pat rose.*?flower
% regexp -all -inline $pat $str
{rose is an flower} {rose is an flower} {rose is a flower} {rose is a color and an flower}
```

(Other command echo not quoted for clarity.)

I have a nasty suspicion that you actually want to do something more general, but I can only answer the questions that you pose.

Comment: You say everything that I would have said, including my concerns about what's really going on…

Comment: @nurdglaw thanks for responding, again i changed the question. pls ,make me clarify that too

Answer (score 1):

With your *revised* question, you need a pretty horrible RE to get exactly what you want:

```
% regexp -all -inline {rose(?:\s*(?!rose)\S)*} $string
{rose is an flower} {rose is an flower} {rose is a flower} {rose is not a place}
```

If you don't mind some extra spaces, you can use this simpler one:

```
% regexp -all -inline {rose(?:(?!rose).)*} $string
{rose is an flower } {rose is an flower } {rose is a flower } {rose is not a place}
```

However, I think you are not telling us what the real thing you're doing is. Regular Expressions are *very* specific to what you're trying to do; generalizing them isn't trivial.